# Unable to load style.css in Django 1.9

Tags: html, css, django, python-2.7, django-1.9

I am trying to load the style.css on my page.
I've added the path for `STATICFILES_DIRS` like below,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
 ]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn")

index.html
{% load staticfiles %}
`<link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/style.css" %}' type='text/css'>`
```

When I ran the `collectstatic` and it collected the `style.css`.

When I do inspect element and open a link of `style.css` `(http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css)`, it gives me `not found` message.

I tried hard-coding the path to `style.css` but, no luck.

I created the another sample project and followed the same steps and `style.css` loaded successfully. 
When I do inspect element and open a link of `style.css`, it shows me html code.

I am really helpless. Any help is really appreciated.

**Edit**

```
setting.py template settings:

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Directory structure:

```
 |myproject
  |----- MyApp/
  |---- myProject/
  |---- static/ 
  |---- static_cdn/
  |----manage.py
```

https://github.com/prafullarkamble/UnableToLoadStyle.css/

Comment: Is this in development (running `manage.py runserver`?) or in production? If it's in production, then please show your server config (e.g. apache/nginx). Did you run `collectstatic`? Where is the `style.css` file located on your disk?

Comment: @Alasdair  Its in development. I did run `collectstatic` and `style.css` is located in `BASE_DIR\static\css`

Comment: can you show your template settings?

Comment: @root-kidz template is loading fine. Its just `style.css` not loading.  Updated the question

Comment: Could you post how are organized your folders?

Comment: @PRK mabe you don't load static, are you using {% load staticfiles %}?

Comment: Could you have a url pattern that is matching `/static/.../` before the static files handler?

Comment: @root-kidz, Yes, I've used `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: @Alasdair I am sorry, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @itepifanio Updated the question with directory structure

Comment: I think there might be an issue with your url patterns, but you haven’t included them in your question so I can’t tell.

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly, the `collectstatic` command is only used for production. So the collected statifiles do not affect the development.

In your project structure, the path to the `style.css` is :

`Salmon/static/Salmon/style.css`.

So you should find the file with the URL:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/Salmon/style.css`

which should be equivalent to `{% static "Salmon/style.css" %}` in your template.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd  `style.css` at `BASE_DIR\static` folder but, that did not help so I kept it in  `myapp\static\myappname\style.css` but, no luck.

Comment: If your file is at `myapp\static\myappname\style.css` you should reach it with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/myappname/style.css` or with `{% static "myappname/style.css" %}` in your template.

Comment: I shold reach it but, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/Salmon/style.css` gives me `url not found`

Answer (score 0):

1) Select the folder(s) where you want the static assets *from*  where you want them to be collected:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "i_will_collect_from_here"),
    ... yet another folder
]
```

2) Select the folder where you want the static assets *to be* collected:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "here_my_static_will_be_collected")
```

3) Run `python manage.py collectstatic`

**Note:**

In `STATICFILES_DIRS` you can add any path you want, it can be an absolute path. `collectstatic` will place the static in your `STATIC_ROOT`.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/var/www/assets/bootstrap/'
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I want files to be collected from `BASE_DIR\static` and to be collected in `BASE_DIR\static_cdn`.  When I run `collectstatic`, I can see it collects `style.css` in `static_cdn` but, it does not render on page. I get `not found` in console/ network tab of browser.